# HTTP POSTS being dropped

Tags: c#, .net, http, post

I am trying to send out a number of HTTP POST requests in parallel. I send them off but not all of them come back. This happens when I use localhost or a remote server. But the same transmitter can send off to a different receiver and it works okay.

Is there a setting that needs to be set on the receiving end to allow multiple POSTs to come in?

The server side code is not complicated:

```
public class Startup
    {

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHealthChecks();
            //ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            // add the EndpointRoutingMiddleware
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
                endpoints.MapGet("/", HandleGet);
                endpoints.MapPost("/", HandlePost);
            });
        }

        private async Task HandleGet(HttpContext context)
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Responding to GET");
        }

        private async Task HandlePost(HttpContext context)
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Responding to POST");
        }
    }
```

The client side just uses a Parallel.ForEach.

EDIT: Here is the client code. I tried using Tasks instead of Parallel.Foreach. 
I would expect this code to output a number of timestamps equal to the number of Tasks created, but it randomly drops some of them.

```
public void PostMultipleStripped(string url, int count)
        {
            int i;

            // create some transactions
            var transactionTasks = new List<Task>();

            for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                // create and start a task
                transactionTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PostSingleTranStripped(url)));
                Thread.Sleep(1);

            }
            // wait for the tasks
            Task.WaitAll(transactionTasks.ToArray());

        }


        private void PostSingleTranStripped(string url)
        {
            string responseMessage = "";

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "JSON";
            request.Timeout = 20000;

            // Get the request stream
            Stream POSTstream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data bytes in the request stream (minimal JSON object)
            byte[] dataByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{}");
            POSTstream.Write(dataByte, 0, dataByte.Length);
            POSTstream.Close();

            // Get response from server
            using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                responseMessage = stream.ReadToEnd();
            }
            debug += DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff") +Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: the client side may be simple but you should include it anyway

Answer (score 1):

`Parellel.ForEach` is designed for running synchronous operations in parallel. HTTP requests by nature are asynchronous. Consequently, you will not reliably be able to run parallel HTTP requests with `Parallel.ForEach`. A recommendation for parallel HTTP requests is to process in batches and then await all of the tasks:

EDIT:
I noticed a few things in your updated code that can be improved. All of your HTTP code can be moved to using `HttpClient` and `HttpRequest`. This is a more modern approach to HTTP development in ASP.NET Core. You get to utilize async/await on `HttpRequest` objects and not need to spin up a new task with `Task.Factory`. Make sure that your methods return tasks and not void if you're going to use async/await. Lastly, you are using `Task.WaitAll` in your PostMultipleStripped function without awaiting that task so it would run synchronously.

Here's some updated example code to reflect your client changes:

```
private static readonly HttpClient _client;

public MyService() {
    _client = new HttpClient();
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> PostData(string url) {
    var data = new StringContent("{}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, data);

    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return result;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> PostDataParallelBatch(IEnumerable<string> urls) 
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
    var batchSize = 100;
    int batchCount = (int) Math.Ceiling((double)urls.Count() / batchSize);
    for(int i = 0; i < batchCount; i++) 
    {
        var currentUrls = urls.Skip(i * batchSize).Take(batchSize);
        tasks.Add(GetData(currentUrls));
    }

    return (await Task.WhenAll(tasks)).SelectMany(d => d);
}
```

When calling this parallel batch post method, you need to remember to await the task, otherwise it will run synchronously:

```
var results = await _myService.PostDataParallelBatch(urls);
```

Comment: Here is the client-side code. I create a list of Tasks and the result is the same as with the Parallel.Foreach: